# SOAP UI how to configure a PUT request body programmatically

Tags: groovy, soapui, put

I'm configuring some requests programmatically in my test cases, I can set headers, custom properties, teardown scripts, etc. however I can't find how to set a standard json body for my put requests. 
Is there any possibility from the restMethod class ?

So far I end up getting the method used :

```
restService = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getInterfaceAt(0)

resource = restService.getOperationByName(resource_name)
request = resource.getRequestAt(0) 
httpMethod = request.getMethod()

if (httpMethod.toString().equals("PUT"))
```

but then I'm stuck trying to find how to set a standard body for my PUT requests.
I try with the getRequestParts() method but it didn't give me what I expected ...

can anyone help, please

thank you

Alexandre

Answer (score 0):

I’ve managed this.  I had a tests of tests where I wanted to squirt the content of interest into the “bare bones” request.  Idea being that I can wrap this in a data driven test.  Then, for each row in my data spreadsheet I pull in the request body for my test.  At first I simply pulled the request from a data source value in my spreadsheet, but this became unmanageable in my spreadsheet.

So, another tactic.  In my test data sheet (data source) I stored the file name that contains the payload I want to squirt in.

In the test itself, I put in a groovy step immediately before the the step I want to push the payload into.

The groovy script uses the data source to firstly get the file name containing the payload, I then read the contents of the file.

In the step I want to push the data into, I just use a get from data, e.g. {groovyStep#result}.

If this doesn’t completely make sense, let me know and I’ll update with screenshot when I have access to SoapUi.

Comment: that's a nice trick, however it goes beyond my needs. The fact is I just want to populate the body part of all my requests with a standard pattern, I dont't particularly need dynamic behaviour